# QGIS displaying polygon that is crossing the 180 meridian

Tags: qgis, postgis, visualisation

I have the following table

```
create table schema.table
(
    id bigint,
    geography geography
);
```

with the following geography

```
INSERT INTO schema.table (id, geography) VALUES (1, '0103000020E61000000100000006000000820DAB1F7BC86440D91A1EB605D733C024C27A3479CB61409763729D583728C0755E7C3479CB614091CC699D583728401184AA1F7BC864404AA108B605D73340808702B3EB7166C095D626E80B2E31BE820DAB1F7BC86440D91A1EB605D733C0');
```

This describes a simple hexagon that is crossing the 180th meridian, but QGIS displays is as follows.
[image]

**Permise:** I cannot change `geography` to `geometry`. And I have thousands of polygons that have the same issue, manual fixing is not an option.

I have looked at `ST_ShiftLongitude` and `ST_WrapX` as I have worked with these functions before, but they only apply to `geometry` data.

**Question:** What settings do I have to change in QGIS to get the right visualization?

**Note:** In PostGIS, e.g. `ST_Intersects` and `ST_DWithin` work just fine.

QGIS version
3.4.3-Madeira

**Update 1:**

I was able to get a visually acceptable solution with

`SELECT id, st_wrapx(st_shiftlongitude(geography::geometry), 180, -360) as geom FROM schema.table;`

Essentially the tip that is crossing the 180th is cut off and placed on the 'left' side of the map. However, this only works for polygons that are actually crossing the 180th.

Also, I made a mistake, it is a pentagon, **not** a hexagon in this example.

`ST_IsValid` returns true and I could not see a self-intersection.

```
POLYGON((
166.265029749 -19.839930899,
142.358545532 -12.108097954,
142.358545535 12.108097953,
166.265029748 19.839930894,
-179.560021882 -0.000000004,
166.265029749 -19.839930899))
```

Comment: What QGIS version and CRS/Projection are you using? I've tried to replicate your question with the same result in QGIS 3.4.4 and multiple projections.

Comment: you need to change to a projection that doesn't split the world at 180, some of the New Zealand ones come to mind

Comment: There is not a configuration in QGIS for that. Given the coordinates of the polygon, in that coordinate system, the internal region of the polygon is well defined by QGIS. Although it looks bad, and we know that the -179 longitude is close to the 179, for that coordinate system that is not true. In the polygons that you have in the background, the polygon of Antarctica has points defined in longitude 180; Russia has, in its multipolygon feature, a continental part defined for positive lengths and another part for negative longitudes.

Comment: If you could create different parts, divided at the intersection of your polygons with the +180 / -180 longitude, these would look exactly as you wish in that coordinate system.